# React Previous State -> What purpose does prevData Serve Here?

Tags: reactjs, react-state

Im going through some React tutorials using state and have encountered some code that I don't understand that I think relates to previous state when setting state in the React code.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

function LoginForm() {
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState({
  email: '',
  password: ''
  });

function emailEnteredHandler(event) {
  //Confused about prevData
  setUserData(prevData => ({
  email: event.target.value,
  password: prevData.password
  }));
};

function passwordEnteredHandler(event) {
  //Confused about prevData
  setUserData( prevData => ({ 
  email: prevData.email,
  password: event.target.value
  }));
};

return (
  <form>
    <input
    type="email"
    placeholder="Your email"
    onBlur={emailEnteredHandler} />
    
    <input
    type="password"
    placeholder="Your password"
    onBlur={passwordEnteredHandler} />
  </form>
  );
  };

    export function App(props) {
    return (
    <div className='App'>
    <LoginForm />
    </div>
    );
    }
```

What purpose does `prevData` serve in this example?

The tutorial indicates that this is for previous state, but in this example previous state doesn't seem to be addressed.

I have a working example [here](https://playcode.io/1796511)

I was experimenting with placing console.log statements in the code as shown here:

[image: console.log]

But that wasn't successful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can only check inside setUserData not outside of that.

it is a previous state if you useState() init with some value and then value you can access as a previous state, for example 

const [text, setText] = useSate(')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can only check inside setUserData not outside of that.

it is a previous state if you `useState()` init with some value and then value you can access as a previous state, for example

```
const [text, setText] = useState('hello')
setText(prav => prav.concat('world'))
consle.log(text)// the text will be 'helloworld'
```

your given code. you can check this way to get output. what is going into it?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function LoginForm() {
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState({
    email: '',
    password: '',
  });

  /*If any one input field is typed first another field will show empty because initial state sets are empty string It makes sense*/

  function emailEnteredHandler(event) {
    setUserData(prevData => {
      return {
        email: event.target.value,
        password: prevData.password,
      };
    });
  }

  function passwordEnteredHandler(event) {
    setUserData(prevData => {
      console.log('prevData email=' + prevData.email);
      return {
        email: prevData.email,
        password: event.target.value,
      };
    });
  }

  return (
    <form>
      <input
        type='email'
        placeholder='Your email'
        onBlur={emailEnteredHandler}
      />
      <input
        type='password'
        placeholder='Your password'
        onBlur={passwordEnteredHandler}
      />
    </form>
  );
}

export function App(props) {
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <h1>Hello React.</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <LoginForm />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I updated my playcode.io example to reflect your code above however not seeing any value for prevData.password.

Comment: you console.log() into emialEnterHandler so whenever you type something on the email field then you can prevData.password value That makes sense right!

if we type email first the password field already is empty so we will see the output is empty, but first type the password then with the email you can see the output on password value.

I hope you get the answer.

Comment: If you still have any queries about this here is my discord handle @robiul692